# JPA2 JoinColumns JoinColumn name is not being respected. (Hibernate 3.6 and H2)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Here is the reduced snippet, omitting the IdClass details. The issue I am having is the tables definition is:

```
ClientPersonalityModel
(
 client_id int not null,
 personality_trait_id int not null,
 personality_type_id int not null,
 primary key (client_id, personality_trait_id, personality_type_id)
)
```

And the class is:

```
@Entity
public class ClientPersonalityModel
{
    @Id 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
    protected ClientModel client;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="personality_trait_id",referencedColumnName="id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="personality_type_id",referencedColumnName="personality_type_id")
    })
    protected ClientPersonalityTraitModel trait;
}
```

But the persistence framework is trying to use columns CLIENT_ID, TRAIT_ID, TRAIT_PERSONALITY_TYPE_ID.

Why are the @JoinColumn names being ignored?

It throws an exception:

Initial sessionFactory creationfailed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find logical column name from physical name personality_type_id in table client_personalities

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find logical column name from physical name personality_type_id in table client_personalities

This case is covered in many examples, but without overriding the column names.

Ex:

Listing 10-12. Project with Dependent Identifier

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProjectId.class)
public class Project {
    @Id private String name;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    private Department dept;
    // ...
}
```

from Pro JPA 2 (ISBNs 978-1-4302-1956-9 / 978-1-4302-1957-6)

Comment: there seems to be a more fundamental issue at hand: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6754

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try switching to `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns/@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`, respectively.

It helped in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273046/how-to-force-openjpa-1-2-2-to-eager-load-a-manytoone-combined-primary-key/7327031#7327031), I believe it might be the same reason.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this case, since I am using JPA2 I should be able to do this. See page 285 of PRO JPA 2.

Comment: @JasonPyeron Thanks for explaining, I wasn't aware that this changed in JPA 2.